# Flutter String.contains(substring) fails when there is a space

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

Using String.contains(substring) to generate a list out of another fails when there is a space in my input.

Here is my code :

```dart
List<String> finalSuggestions = suggestions.where((i) => i.contains(new RegExp(pattern,caseSensitive:false, unicode: true))).toList();
```

As `suggestions` is a list of strings, and `pattern` is the user input. everything works fine unless the users adds a space in the string he is typing . `finalSuggesions` becomes null. else .. as long as the `pattern` is only a single word it is all fine.

Comment: How about you erase all space before run 'suggestions.where'?

Comment: If none of your suggestions contains a space, then it makes sense that a space in the pattern would result in no matched suggestions. What exactly is your question here?

Comment: all of my suggestions have a space between 2 words .. but when the user finishes the 1st word then press space .. the result shows noting !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need to use `RegExp`, Because `pattern` a string and `suggestions`
a list of String.

```
List<String> finalSuggestions = suggestions.where((i) => i.contains(pattern)).toList();
```

It shouldn't be affected by space in this case

Comment: A space isn't a special character, and even if it was, special characters don't need to be escaped when they come from user input.

Comment: Now your code won't compile because `pattern.toString` is a method and needs to be called with `()`. Regardless, though, `pattern` is already a string, so calling `toString` on it is redundant.